# How to store in text file, a number of arrays (vectors) as columns NOT rows

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have generated two sinusoidal waves, which I named as "y1" and "y2". Both are a function of time variable "x". To further process the data using another script, I need to save these in a txt or csv file, looking something like this:

```
Time(s)    Title for y1    Title for y2
1               float...      float...
2               float...      float...
...             ....          ....
1000            ....          ....
```

```
import numpy as np

N = 600  # number of sample points
d = 0.1  # time domain [s]
f = 50   # frequency [Hz or 1/s]
T = 1/f  # period [s]
s = d/N  # sampling time interval [s]

# sine wave 1
u = 1  
du = 0.1  
x = np.linspace(0.0, d, N)
y1 = u + u*du* np.sin(2*np.pi*x*f)

# sine wave 2
q = 0.8  
dq = 0.1  
phi = np.pi/2  # phase delay (rad)
y2 = q + q*dq* np.sin(2*np.pi*x*f - phi)

# export data to csv file
np.savetxt('output/signal.csv', [x,y1,y2], delimiter=',')
```

Doing that, what I get as output is a csv with the 3 arrays listed in rows. What is desirable is to have that trasposed into 3 columns instead. There should be an easier way ( I assume) than generating a matrix through a loop. Trying a variety of methods, didn't work so far.

Answer (score 0):

The following NumPy function did the trick.

```
z=np.vstack((x, y1, y2)).T
np.savetxt('output/signal.csv', z, delimiter=',')
```